# Application Azure will be Aborted when upload publish file with Startup task

Tags: azure

I have created web application and one agent (EXE) with it fetch performance counter using WMI Query (compatible with 32 bit) so i have created one Enable32BitAppPool1.cmd file and add it in startup task, content of that file as per below

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd  set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true

and set property of that file "Copy Always" as per following [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/03/migrating-32bit-asp-net-application-to-windows-azure-web-role.aspx).

Now when i am going to upload that package to Azure then it will be Aborted or in Buzy mode
Can anyone please tell me the reason of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your cmd file not working in startup task. 
Two possible solution 
1> Create .bat file and try in as a start up task for your webrole.
2> other solution is that, try to run the file (.cmd) using system.Diagostic.process.start(...) from some other exe file and set that exe file as a startup task.

Comment: Great! I have resolved my problem using your 2nd option system.Diagostic.process.start(), still i would like to know the issue with CMD file..

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to know, based on what you've posted, what's going on.

I'd enable remote desktop on that instance and check out the event logs to try and get a handle on what's happening.

If you can't remote desktop in because your startup task is killing it - then disable the startup task, remote desktop in, and try to run what you think the startup task is doing - but manually - so you can see what's actually going on.

Comment: I have already run that command inside cmd file after connecting RDP before and it's working file.